# Preserving the value of ViewData MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, viewdata

I am working on MVC 4 where i have "ActionResult" method which is of login page, username and password are entered in textbox, based on the username(which is billnumber) after login it should pull the data of that respective billnumber(username), so currently everything is working fine, I am able to get the username from one view and send it to another for further verification, I have stored "username" and "usertypeID" in Viewdata and that value is passed to next view, but the data on ViewData will not stand for longer time, and even if we try to refresh the page multiple times(10 to 20 times), below are the code which i Have used to store and to access

this is where i store the value

```
   public ActionResult ValidateLogIn(FormCollection postedFormData)
    {
        // codes
  TempData["UsrName"] = LoginViewModel.LoginDataModel.UserName;
            // codes

 }


  public ActionResult LandingPage()
    {           
        ViewData["message"] = TempData["UsrName"].ToString();
        ViewData["person"] =Convert.ToInt32(TempData["UserTypeID"]);
        TempData.Keep();

        PatientDetailsViewModel PatientDetailsViewModel = new PatientDetailsViewModel();
          String PatID = Convert.ToString(ViewData["message"].ToString());
        int PersonType = Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["person"]);
          
             PatientUnderDoctorDetailsViewModel = PatientUnderDoctorDataAccessService.PatientUnderDocLogInEnquiry(PatID);
   }
```

**this is where i store it on viewdata**

```
        ViewData["message"] = TempData["UsrName"].ToString();
        ViewData["person"] =Convert.ToInt32(TempData["UserTypeID"]);
        TempData.Keep();
```

**AND HERE IS WHERE I GET VALUES FROM VIEWDATA**

```
        String PatID = Convert.ToString(ViewData["message"].ToString());
        int PersonType = Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["person"]);
```

I am passing PatID and PersonType as parameter to next method,

at beginning I wasn't using TempData.keep(); so when I refresh the page atleast once used to get error, tried searching and found TempData but i believe it is not much efficient for longer time, if I left application idle for 5 mins and then refreshes the page once , it generates error message since tempdata is empty(null)

**WHAT I NEED**

let me know is there any mistake i have done, or is there any better way to fix this issue, where data can be stored in variable until I quit the application

[image]

Comment: Why no using `Session` object?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @inanikian, I had lot of confusion between sesson vs viewdata, where some of websites suggested more on ViewData, which made to try it(please let me know if I am wrong), and if really session can be used more than Viewdata, I dont mind using it, but I just need to transport the parameters not to store data as cookies, let me which is best ,thanks

Comment: You can use TempData or Session for this.

Comment: @narayanaswamy, above code I have used TempData saved it it viewdata variable then to string variable passed as parameter, I have added one more line of code which i have already used, thanks

Comment: Please update the code. It is not clear by saying this is where I store. Could you please put the view or the action where you use it.

Comment: You can have it , this is how username has taken and sent,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link will help you [State Management In MVC](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/9KHW190712-ViewData-vs-ViewBag-vs-TempData-vs-Session.html)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this article, but I already have gone through this article, and it briefs what is all about, not shows how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Temp data for this. it will be lost when the app pool refreshes or if you use another process (web garden).

User.Identity.Name will return the name of a validated user.

If you are passing data around you should be using Models and not ViewData or TempData or ViewBag.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually I am passing this Value(username) from one View to another, I believe(let me know If i am wrong) User.identity.Name mostly works when using for same page, So I preferred to use ViewData

Comment: User.Identity.Name is available on every view, you don't need to pass it about. Try it out.